# query has no destination for result data error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am having the following function in `

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_avalable_providers(
  start_day_id integer,
  end_day_id integer,
  number_of_days integer,
  requested integer)
    RETURNS SETOF provider AS
$BODY$declare
required integer;
available_product integer;
p provider;
p_id integer;
noa integer;
begin
   FOR p IN SELECT * FROM provider
   loop     
      FOR p_id, noa IN SELECT id, number_of_availables FROM product
         WHERE provider_id = p.id
   LOOP
    required = requested/noa;
                      select available_product = 
                   public.get_available_products_biggerthan(
        start_day_id, end_day_id, number_of_days, required, p_id);
     if available_product = number_of_days then
          return next p;
            exit;         
         end if;
      END LOOP;  
  end loop;   

  return;
  end;         
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
 ROWS 1000;
 ALTER FUNCTION public.get_avalable_providers(integer, integer, integer, 
      integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The above functions is supposed to return some providers that have sufficient amount of the requested `product` in a days range 
it is taking advantage anther function `get_available_products_biggerthan` and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function 
get_avalable_products(integer,integer,integer,integer,integer) line 15 at 
SQL statement
```

**Question**
where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

> The result of a SQL command yielding a single row (possibly of
>   multiple columns) can be assigned to a record variable, row-type
>   variable, or list of scalar variables. This is done by writing the
>   base SQL command and adding an INTO clause

try below (I only fixed obvious syntax):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_avalable_providers(
  start_day_id integer,
  end_day_id integer,
  number_of_days integer,
  requested integer)
    RETURNS SETOF provider AS
$BODY$declare
required integer;
available_product integer;
p provider;
p_id integer;
noa integer;
begin
   FOR p IN (SELECT * FROM provider)
   loop     
      FOR p_id, noa IN (SELECT id, number_of_availables FROM product
         WHERE provider_id = p.id)
   LOOP
    required = requested/noa;
    select public.get_available_products_biggerthan(
        start_day_id, end_day_id, number_of_days, required, p_id) INTO available_product ;
     if available_product = number_of_days then
          return next p;
            exit;         
         end if;
      END LOOP;  
  end loop;   

  return;
  end;         
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
 ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: sorry what was the obvious syntax error because I have changed some names and posted the functions so it's not easy to notice that for me

Comment: I select value `INTO variable`